# How to send and receive Ctrl key to .Net Core console application via Putty SSH?

Tags: c#, linux, ssh, .net-core, console

I have a .Net Core 2 console application running on an Ubuntu server.

I ssh to the server via Putty from Windows.

When I try to send anything with a "ctrl" preceeding it, I see that the application doesn't receive the ctrl key signal.

Is this a Putty-specific issue preventing the ctrl key being sent at all? Or is there something specific about working with special keys on Linux or via SSH that is preventing my application from recognizing the key stroke?

Here is my code (it works when run directly on my Windows machine):

```
var programCanceler = new CancellationTokenSource();

log?.Information("Press ctrl+q to shut down application");

while (!programCanceler.IsCancellationRequested)
{

    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);

        //The following line does not fire when I press ctrl
        //but it does fire when I press Q -- regardless of whether I'm holding ctrl
        log?.Information($"Key Pressed: {key.Key}");

        //Additionally, the following line never evaluates to true
        //so even a ctrl+key combination isn't being recognized
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Q && key.Modifiers.HasFlag(ConsoleModifiers.Control))
        {
            programCanceler.Cancel();
            log?.Information("Shutdown request issued...");
        }
    }

    Thread.Sleep(300);
}
```

Comment: This very question has been answered on superuser. https://superuser.com/questions/913757/why-keys-like-esc-ctrl-shift-and-alt-does-not-work-in-ssh-session-from-my-wind